# Grails f:field display selected dropdown

Tags: select, grails, gsp

Hi I am very new in Grails and I have a very simple question in grails and I hope someone can help me.

I have a simple domain class Person as follows:

```
class Person {

    String  name    //  name of the person
    Date    dob     //  date of birth

}   // end of class
```

I already have a few Person entries in my database.

In another form, I want to let the users select the name of the person whose age is above 21 from a dropdown list. Right now it looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="form">

    <f:field bean="Person" property="name" />

</fieldset>
```

How do I filter all the other people from the database and only display the names of the people who above 21 years old?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you can use `Person.findAllByDobGreaterThanEquals(someVariableDate)` and check at docs: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html

Comment: Thanks @fsi. This works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the people who are older than 21 years old in the controller, then pass it to the gsp for display. Something like this:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def create() {

// all your other codes
def adults = Person.findAllByDobGreaterThanEquals(new Date() - 21.year) 

// other codes....
respond new Person(params), model:[adults :adults]
}
```

Then display it in the gsp with the resultset.

```
<fieldset class="form">

    <f:field bean="Person" property="name" >
        <g:select name="name" from="${adults}" optionKey="id" />
    </f:field>

</fieldset>
```